# i am trying to provide client side validation for password using jquery, but the form gets submitted without validating. i am ew to jquery as well

Tags: jquery-plugins

**i am trying to provide client side validation for password using jquery, but the form gets submitted without validating. i am new to jquery as well.**

what i am trying here 
1)checking for the password fields, should be not null 
2)comparing both the passwords. 
but the form gets submitted, and i could not find the error.

Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Form Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myform").validate({
                    //onkeyup: false;
                    debug: true;
                    rules: {
                        password: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 6,
                            maxlength: 12,
                            password: true
                        },
                        password1: {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: "#password"
                        }
                    },

                    messages: {
                        password: {
                            required: "req",
                            minlength: "min",
                            maxlength: "max"
                         }
                        password1: {
                            required: "req re",
                            equalTo: "not equal"
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            label.error { width: 250px; display: inline; color: red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">
            <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" />
            <label for="password" generated="true" class="error"></label>

            <br/>

            <label for="password1">Retype password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password1" id="password1" value="" />
            <label for="password1" generated="true" class="error"></label>

            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="join" />
            <input type="submit" value="cancel" class="cancel" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your validate function and it'll work fine

1) Remove the line `debug: true;`
2) You have missed a comma in the messages section. Add a comma to after the first message, as follows...

```
messages: {
    password: {
        required: "req",
        minlength: "min",
        maxlength: "max"
    },
    password1: {
        required: "req re",
        equalTo: "not equal"
    }
}
```

Comment: hi neo, thanks for the reply. it is working fine now :), but still there's one problem, when the length of the password is proper and there is a password mismatch then also the form gets submitted after showing the error. i changed input type="text" to input type="password" as well. What should be done..

Comment: in other words i can say that it checks only the reqiured field of the first password field and it checks for the min and max values only.

Comment: @user1239386: remove the line `password: true` in the rules section.